# http get запрос golang

Tags: golang, http

Хотел обратиться по http через golang, но не выходит. Если обращаюсь через браузер, то всё работает,несколько раз проверил. Делал по [примеру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478577/why-does-json-unmarshal-work-with-reference-but-not-pointer), выводится пустота при вызове метода Parse. В чём ошибка?

```
type WebParse struct {
    Pass           string
    RefreshTimeMin int
    MyClient       *http.Client
}

type JSONanswer struct {
    Text string
}

func New(pass string, refreshTimeMin int) *WebParse {
    myClient := &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}
    return &WebParse{pass, refreshTimeMin, myClient}
}


func (webPars WebParse) Parse() {
    feeds := webPars.getFeeds()
    fmt.Println("feeds = ", feeds.Text) // тут соответсвенно тоже выводит пустоту
}

func (webPars WebParse) getFeeds() *JSONanswer {
    url := "точно рабочий адрес"
    passParam := "pass=" + webPars.Pass
    params := "?" + passParam
    resp := JSONanswer{}
    err := webPars.getJson(url+params, &resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error WebParse :: getFeeds : ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("resp = ", resp.Text) // тут выводит пустоту
    return &resp
}

func (webPars WebParse) getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
    // fmt.Println(url) /// вывод проверял - линк верный
    r, err := webPars.MyClient.Get(url)
    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}
```

Comment: Структурные теги к полям не добавил: https://www.practical-go-lessons.com/post/how-to-add-and-read-go-struct-tags-cbt2mue6togs70jopvi0

Comment: JSON кодек игнорирует незнакомые поля и сохраняет только те, которые указаны в структуре. У вас в структуре единственное поле `Text`. Уверены, что у вас в ответе есть поле `Text`? Поменяйте тип JSONanswer на `type JSONanswer map[string]any` и посмотрите, что там на самом деле грузится из сети.